# If $abc+1=0$, verify that'

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $abc+1=0$, prove that:
$\frac {1}{1-a-b^{-1}}+\frac {1}{1-b-c^{-1}} +\frac {1}{1-c-a^{-1}}=1$.

My Attempt:

$abc+1=0$

$abc=-1$.

Now,

$$L.H.S=\frac {1}{1-a-b^{-1}}+\frac {1}{1-b-c^{-1}}+\frac {1}{1-c-a^{-1}}$$

$$=\frac{b}{b-ab-1} + \frac {1}{1-b-c^{-1}} + \frac {c^{-1}}{c^{-1}-1-(ca)^{-1}}$$

$$=\frac{b}{b+c^{-1} -1} +\frac{1}{1-b-c^{-1}} +\frac{c^{-1}}{c^{-1}-1+b}$$

What should I do next?

Comment: Just do it ! :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on the correct path. Your steps are all correct. Proceeding from there, just note that

$$\frac{b}{b+c^{-1} -1} +\frac{1}{1-b-c^{-1}} +\frac{c^{-1}}{c^{-1}-1+b}$$
$$=\frac{b+c^{-1}}{b+c^{-1} -1} -\frac{1}{b+c^{-1}-1}$$
$$=\frac{b+c^{-1}-1}{b+c^{-1} -1}$$
$$=1$$

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 2):

$$\dfrac1{1-a-b^{-1}}=\dfrac{bc}{bc-abc-c}=\dfrac{bc}{bc+1-c}$$

$$\dfrac1{1-b-c^{-1}}=\dfrac{-c}{-c+bc+1}$$

As $-abc=1,-a^{-1}=bc$
$$\dfrac1{1-c-a^{-1}}=\dfrac1{1-c+bc}$$